# better string ellipse implementation

Tags: .net

I want to ellipse string if length exceeds a certain limit. I have seen many examples for ellipse from a simple one that only take substring if a limit exceeds to other consider taking full words so that it won't break sentence readability and not to trim words in half.

Mobile phone use to trim text based on the second approach. I wanted to know if there any way we can go further with string ellipse implementation? like consider `,` `( )` `[ ]` etc?

this is what i have done so far

```
public static string TrimString(string str, int charLength)
        {
            if (str.Length >= charLength)
            {
                str = str.Substring(0, charLength - 3);
                var chunks = str.Split(' ');
                if(chunks.Length >1)
                    chunks = chunks.Take(chunks.Length - 1).ToArray();
                str = string.Format("{0}...", string.Join(" ", chunks));
            }
            return str;
        }
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of methods in org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.

Comment: i was wondering if there is something like algorithm or source code for it?

Comment: Here is the source code link: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/lang/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.java?view=markup. You can look for a method "abbreviateMiddle"

Comment: sorry i saw the code but abbreviatemiddle is something else.. its not what i am looking for